# Dynamically create and animate text/shapes (HTML5/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, animate-cc

I'm a JS/HTML5 newbie trying to animate an IRC chat using HTML5/JS in Animate CC. My goal is to dynamically create rounded rectangles with text from the chat and load them onto the canvas from the bottom. New messages would pop up from the bottom of the list and push the other messages upwards.

Currently, I have the WebSocket set up and listening for messages. When it detects a message it sends it to the queue where it checks if any animation is currently playing, then if not it generates a rounded rectangle and the message text and animates it coming up from the bottom of the screen.

My problem now is, if I send another message, another instance of this rounded rectangle is created and animates on top of the old one. I'm not sure how to access the properties of the old message to push it upwards as they are dynamically created.

I have thought about using arrays with a certain length (so as to not take up the whole screen) but I had a little trouble implementing it. I also thought about creating a global variable with the number of messages currently on the screen which could increment with each new instance, however, this would only be useful for stacking upwards. It wouldn't push the list itself upwards.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could approach this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Edit: some parts I have so far. At the bottom, the message is generated but I can't access it again.

```
pubsub.listen('message', function (e) {
   // when I get a message, add it to the queue to be animated
   var msg = new Message(e.from, e.text);
   messageQueue.add(msg);
   checkMessages();
)};

function checkMessages() {
    //check if a message is already being animated
    //if not, send call the MessageQueue to dispatch
    //else, wait for animation to finish
}

MessageQueue.prototype.dispatch = function () {
    var msg = this.messages[0] //animate the latest message
    if (msg) {
        generateMessage(msg.from, msg.data); //dynamically create a message
        this.messages.splice(0, 1); //remove this from queue
    }
}

function generateMessage(msgFrom, msgData) {
    animActive = true; //animation now in progress

    var roundRect = new createjs.Shape();
    roundRect.graphics.beginFill("red").drawRoundRectComplex(0, 0, 400, 50, 25, 25, 25, 25);
    roundRect.x = 100;
    roundRect.y = 820;
    stage.addChild(roundRect);

    var text = new createjs.Text(msgData, "15px Gotham", "#ffffff");
    text.x = 150;
    text.y = 855;
    text.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
    stage.addChild(text);

    TweenMax.to(roundRect, 2, {y: 620, ease: Elastic.easeOut});
    TweenMax.to(text, 2, {y: 655, ease: Elastic.easeOut});

    setTimeout(animDeactivate, 2100); //animation has ended
}
```

Comment: May I suggest you add some code to show what you got so far and explain your problem. You can easily [edit] your question to do so. But don't just dump all your code, just what is necessary to demonstrate your problem. Maybe read [ask] to get an idea how you could improve your question and to learn about how you can create a [mcve]

Comment: @mmgross Apologies. I updated it, hopefully it's not more confusing.